# Convert matrix column in R data frame to multiple columns

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

Doing this

```
library(tidyverse)   
df <- tibble(x = runif(5), y = runif(n=25) %>% matrix(nrow = 5, ncol = 5))
```

I get

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
       x y[,1]  [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5]
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 0.0458 0.577 0.325 0.0186 0.354  0.735 
2 0.817  0.611 0.830 0.0421 0.0320 0.666 
3 0.618  0.968 0.611 0.466  0.733  0.0458
4 0.335  0.797 0.279 0.635  0.572  0.125 
5 0.837  0.483 0.965 0.831  0.900  0.674
```

This is a 5 x 2 data frame. The second column `y` is a matrix. I would like this to be a 5 x 6 data frame with each column of the 5x5 matrix being its own column in the data frame.

I assumed that there would be some easy way to do this using something like `tidyr::unnest`, but that doesn't work. Naively trying that leads to the following error.

```
> unnest(df, y)
Error: Assigned data `map(data[[col]], as_df, col = col)` must be compatible with existing data.
x Existing data has 5 rows.
x Assigned data has 25 rows.
ℹ Only vectors of size 1 are recycled.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Am I missing something, or do I have to do something like this?

```
> bind_cols(x = df$x, as_tibble(df$y))
# A tibble: 5 x 6
       x    V1    V2     V3     V4     V5
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 0.0458 0.577 0.325 0.0186 0.354  0.735 
2 0.817  0.611 0.830 0.0421 0.0320 0.666 
3 0.618  0.968 0.611 0.466  0.733  0.0458
4 0.335  0.797 0.279 0.635  0.572  0.125 
5 0.837  0.483 0.965 0.831  0.900  0.674
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option with `do.call` with `data.frame`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df %>%
          do.call(data.frame, .) %>%
          as_tibble
```

---

Or use `unnest_wider`

```
df %>% 
    mutate(y = as.data.frame(y)) %>%
    unnest_wider(y)
```

Comment: also `invoke(data.frame, df)` or even `lift(data.frame)(df)` etc